# Which iOS 3D Engine should I choose to display iBook Author like 3D model?

Tags: ios, 3d, simulation, ibooks

I want to display some 3D models in my app, just like the one you can create with iBook Author on iBook2, you can have a 3D model in the view, and pinch to enlarge, enter the 3D model's view. User can rotate and pinch to scale. Which engine should I use to render the 3D model?

Answer (score 2):

i just have used 2d graphics, but have seen this engines:

[dEngine](http://fabiensanglard.net/dEngineSourceCodeRelease/)

[cocos3d](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/)

[isgl3d](http://code.google.com/p/isgl3d/)

or go hardcore and use openGL [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4404/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial-part-2-textures)

let me know how you go!

good luck!